# Why adjusting top in jQuery doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

After scrolling more in my page, I want to change the top offset, but jQuery doesn't adjust this on my element.

I want my element with id goToLog to be fixed on the page after scrolling 80px. This part is working, but when I scroll 260px, my Navbar is also fixed on the top of my page, so I want the button goToLog to be shown underneath the Navbar. So I want to change the top from .2rem to 70px.

I tried to add !important behind the top value in jQuery, or to change the top in css in px, but neither of that seems to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 80) {
      $('#goToLog').css('display', 'block');
      $('#goToLog').on('click', function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      });
    } else if (scroll >= 260) {
      $('#goToLog').css('top', '70px');
    } else {
      $('#goToLog').css('display', 'none');
    }

    if (scroll >= 260) {
      $('#mainnav').addClass('stickynav');
    } else {
      $('#mainnav').removeClass('stickynav');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#info {
  height: 5rem;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

#goToLog,
#logform input[type=submit] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 39px;
}

#goToLog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.stickynav {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0px;
  background: #9C9FB3 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info" class="container">
  <form id="logform" class=" flex" method=POST action="">
    <div><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></div>
  </form><button id="goToLog" class="container" type="button">Login <span class="fas fa-arrow-circle-up"></span></button>
</div>
<header id="mainheader" class="parallax-header" data-parallax="scroll">
  <div style="height:150px"></div>
  <nav id="mainnav" class="">
    <ul class="unlist container">
      <li>nav item</li>
      <li>nav item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

If display block is working in jQuery, I expected top 70px also to work. Why not?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional for setting top:70px is already satisfied by `if (scroll >= 80)`, so this condition gets skipped.

Rather than using `else if (scroll >= 260)` I think you should nest `if (scroll >= 260)` inside `if (scroll >= 80)`. It would look more like:

```
if (scroll >= 80) {
  $('#goToLog').css('display', 'block');
  $('#goToLog').on('click', function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
  if (scroll >= 260) {
    $('#goToLog').css('top', '70px');
  }
} else {
  $('#goToLog').css('display', 'none');
}
```